# R: lookaround that doesn't skip any characters

Tags: r, perl, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to use R to mark the syllable boundaries (with a period) of hypothetical words (made up of sequences of a's and b's) under the following rules:

1. Insert period between any two a's. >> `a.a`, not `aa`
2. If there are two or fewer b's between the two a's, place the period to their left. >> `a.bba`, not `abb.a`
3. Place the period to the right of any additional b's. >> `ab.bba`, not `a.bbba`

I wrote the following lines, which seemed to work at first.

```
S <- c('b{0,2}a(b(?=bb))*') # syllable structure

words <- c('abababa','abbabaabbb','bbabbbba')

p <- function(string){paste0(string,collapse='')} # shorthand collapse to single string

gsub(p(c(S,'\\K(?=',S,')')),'.',words,perl=T)
#[1] "a.ba.ba.ba"    "a.bba.ba.abbb" "bbabb.bba"  # all correct
```

But I tried it on more word and found a problem:

```
words <- c('aaaa','baabbba')
#[1] "a.aa.a"         "ba.abbba"  # should be a.a.a.a / ba.ab.bba
```

Apparently, the problem is that the period failed to insert after an "a" if that "a" is preceded by another "a". I don't believe there's anything wrong with my definition of `S`. Rather, it seems R would skip a character for lookaround if that character has already been used for a previous lookaround.  At any rate, what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The tokens get "consumed" by the regex engine so can't be used twice. Just perform your substitution again:

```
f <- function(words) gsub(p(c(S,'\\K(?=',S,')')),'.',words,perl=T)
f(words)
[1] "a.aa.a"   "ba.abbba"
f(f(words))
[1] "a.a.a.a"   "ba.ab.bba"
```